# Why 'what' is used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Court documents detail **what** a man charged with murder told investigators about the abduction and killing of Mollie Tibbetts.

I'm not sure what '**what**' is doing in this sentence.  'Detail' here is used as a verb. "charged with murder" modifies "a man". "*A man told investigators about the abduction and killing of Mollie Tibbetts*" is the main body of the sub-clause. So, I think '**that**' is just fit.

> Court documents detail **that** a man charged with murder told investigators about the abduction and killing of Mollie Tibbetts.

Any thoughts?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/latest-body-found-rural-area-near-students-hometown-144956162.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion lies in the separation of some sentence elements.

Hopefully, it will make more sense if I rephrase it:

> A man was charged with the abduction and murder of Mollie Tibbets. Court documents detail **what he told investigators** about the crime.

**What** is referencing the content of his story to the investigators.

---

Restating the original question:

> Court documents detail **what a man** charged with murder **told investigators** about the abduction and killing of Mollie Tibbetts.

Because *charged with murder* has been placed in between the words in bold, it makes it more difficult to parse.